# Changing the cursor in ASP.NET while loading doesn't work without a JS alert

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mouse-cursor

I want to change the cursor to an hourglass in my asp.net application to let my users know that the process is running. I searched for an answer and was advised to use JavaScript as follows:

1. Add this JavaScript:

   ```
   function hourglass() {
       document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
   }
   ```
2. then in my code in the page load event:

   ```
   btnImport.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: hourglass();");
   ```

Where btnImport is the button they click on.

However this does not work. If I add an alert to the hourglass function. it does work. Is there some way to get this to work without the alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
btnImport.Attributes.Add("onclick", "hourglass();");
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it an Ajax-Webapp? Then you could use an [UpdateProgress Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743952/best-loading-feedback-for-asp-net/2744316#2744316) to show while the user is waiting till import finished.