# busy mouse cursor when page loading in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, load, pageload, busy-cursor

I just want to inform the user that the page is busy when it is loading or the action is being carried in the background or when the postback occurs by just changing the mouse cursor to busy.

The cursor should turn to normal pointer when the page is completely loaded in ASP.Net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the cursor in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821309/changing-the-cursor-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this from [setHourglass](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1109618.htm)

With ASP.NET pages this is a bit more of a problem to do. You need to employ a little JavaScript.

Add this JavaScript between the  tags on your ASP.NET web page:

Code:

```
 function setHourglass()
 {
   document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
 }
```

Now you have to tell the web form to run the JavaScript funciton when a post back happens.

Add this to your  tag:

Code:

```
     <body onbeforeunload="setHourglass();" onunload="setHourglass();">
```

Also try this [Hourglass-cursor-for-Web-ASP-NET-pages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8243/Hourglass-cursor-for-Web-ASP-NET-pages)

Now to set it back to `normal` do this

```
       document.body.style.cursor='default';
```