# What to import to customize cursor in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

just wanted to ask how to customise the cursor in asp.net using c#.
Currently i tried this code out but it's not working...

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath +  "\\Cursor1.cur");
```

and I got this error:
[image: Error]

I wonder if I need to include more stuff here:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
```

I searched a lot and I can't see others having this kind of problems...

Can you help me?

EDIT:

Actually I wanted to create a web application based in aspx and including a whiteboard in my web page. So I wanted to make it such that when i press the 'pencil' icon, the cursor will change to a pencil. Is it possible?

Comment: You're making a website I guess? You can only change the cursor via C# code when creating a windows form application. For a website, you will need to use CSS, JavaScript or other client side languages instead, like in [this example](http://forums.asp.net/t/681784.aspx?How+to+change+the+Mouse+cursor) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821309/changing-the-cursor-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Draken yeah cos its for a sch project I needed it to be in asp.net form... or is it possible to change from html to c# code in asp.net later on? Sorry am a newcomer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Windows cursor files (.cur) in a web application. For one thing, what will non-Windows devices do with it. The technique you're using is for Windows Forms (desktop) applications.

The way to change the cursor on the web is via CSS properties.

So for instance if you want the cursor to change when the user hovers over a certain image, you could define it like this:

HTML:

```
<img id="Image1" src="myimagefile.jpg"/>
```

CSS:

```
#Image1:hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

For a full list of cursor types you can use, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: well you can use your server-side C# to manipulate the HTML and CSS that is sent back to the browser, yes.

Comment: It's not truly possible to do this with just C# code though, it will always be done where C# manipulates some client side code, like CSS, HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: @Draken but is it possible for me to do it in c# then embed it into my aspx webpage? :))

Comment: @Zoey if you agree this has helped you please accept the answer